# Implementation os NMAE as metric with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to implement the Normalized Mean Squared Error (NMSE) as a metric on Keras. [This is the math of the NMSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak5bq.png).

To do so, I'm trying with this code:

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

def NMSE_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    #nmse = K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred)/K.square(y_true), axis=-1)
    nmse = K.square(y_true - y_pred)/K.square(y_true)
    return nmse
```

The NNet I'm building is this:

```
# NNET
network = Sequential()

network.add(Input(shape=(n_features,1,)))

network.add(LSTM(n_features, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_features,1,))) # LSTM
network.add(Dropout(0.2)) # Dropout

network.add(LSTM(n_features, activation='relu')) # LSTM
network.add(Dropout(0.2)) # Dropout

network.add(Dense(n_features, activation='relu'))

network.add(Dense(1)) # Output

network.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=[NMSE_metric])
epochs = 100

model = network.fit(X_train, y_train
                    , epochs=epochs, batch_size=1
                    , verbose=2
                    )
```

The problem is that NMSE_metric just gave inf. Any hint?

Comment: I suppose `y_true` could be `0` and that will cause the `inf`. If that's the case add a small floating point like `(y_true + 1e-8)` should work.

Comment: Hey, I think you were referring to `y_true`, right? Because it's the variable in the denominator.

But that worked for me, thank you!